# Gem 2.0. Compatibility Issue with ActiveRecord 4.1.2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems

i am trying to conncet with mysql database and to get the data from the that particular database but it is rising an error.., fix it plz

Code is:

```
require 'rubygems'
#require 'mysql'
require 'active_record'


ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    {
    :adapter => 'mysql',
    :host => 'localhost',
    :database => 'spyware',
    :user => 'root',
    :password => 'sqlpass'
    }
)

class Definition<ActiveRecord::Base
end

defni = Definition.Find(:all)

defni.each do |row|

    print "\n\n".row.name
end
```

the Error i am getting is::

```
ruby dbconnect.rb
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:190:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'mysql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:187:in `spec'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
    from dbconnect.rb:6:in `<main>'
>Exit code: 1
```

I am using gem version of 2.0.14 and mysql version is 2.8.1 x86

Answer (score 0):

Rails have already provided answer to you: Add `gem 'mysql'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
Reading error logs is great idea! ;)

Comment: Have you run `bundle install` to install all gems in gemfile?

Comment: can you clearly explain how to run bundle install and els plz